# Box2D interpolation and fixed timestep

Tags: java, box2d, libgdx, interpolation

I´m using Libgdx with Box2D and the R.U.B.E. editor.

I have a problem. A while ago i noticed that the physics behave different depending on device speed, etc.
So I searched for this problem and found the http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/ thing and was confused :D
Now it finally got something to work that make the physics behave the same on all my devices ;)

But I saw that on my faster device my dynamic bodies are jumpy/glitching? or anything like that.
Well, I found that i can interpolate the positions of my bodies, but there is the problem.
I couldn´t find anything that makes the interpolation between the body positions working.

Can anyone show me some code snippets how i can get all my dynamic bodies in my scene and make them to interpolate their positions?
Please help me :?

I post you something I have made.

For the fixed timestep:

Code: Select all

```
public float BOX2D_MAX = 0.25f;
public float BOX2D_STEP = 1 / 60f;

in render() method:

accumulator += dt;          

    if (dt > BOX2D_MAX){
            dt = BOX2D_MAX;
         }
         while (accumulator >= BOX2D_STEP)
         {
            resetsmooth();    

            scene.world.step(BOX2D_STEP, scene.velocityIterations, scene.positionIterations);
            accumulator -= BOX2D_STEP;

         }

         interpolation = accumulator / BOX2D_STEP;
         scene.world.clearForces();             
         smooth();
```

and my try to interpolate my bodies:

Code: Select all

```
public void smooth( ) {


         float minusOne = 1.0f - interpolation;

         bod = scene.world.getBodies();

         //looking up for the bodies in my world
         while(bod.hasNext() == true){

               n = bod.next();

               if(n.getType() == BodyType.DynamicBody){

               smoothX = interpolation * n.getPosition().x + minusOne * nPosX;
               smoothY = interpolation * n.getPosition().y + minusOne * nPosY;
               smoothA = interpolation * n.getAngle() + minusOne * nAng;

               //transform the position
               n.setTransform(smoothX, smoothY, smoothA);   

               }
         }
   }

   public void resetsmooth(){

         bod = scene.world.getBodies();

         //looking up for the bodies in my world
         while(bod.hasNext() == true){

            n = bod.next();

            if(n.getType() == BodyType.DynamicBody){

            //getting bodies position
            nPosX = n.getPosition().x;
            nPosY = n.getPosition().y;
            nAng  = n.getAngle();      

            }
         }
      }
```